# What happens when one Hibernate instance can't reach the second level cache?

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have two serves, each running the same Hibernate application using the same 2nd level cache.
Now suppose one of the serves can't connect to the 2nd level cache (someone put up a firewall rule that prevents the access to the cache cluster).
How does that server work afterwards?
How is data consistency kept between the servers?

Answer (score 1):

Experimentation is called for. But I would bet what you get is an immediate exception from the Hibernate operation that suffered the communications failure, not very different from what would occur if the DB is unavailable.

Comment: I agree that an experiment would provide the answer. I have limited resources to test this out now and wanted to know if anyone encountered this problem. I couldn't find anything about it in the Hibernate documentation or forums.

Answer (score 1):

Practice should be in such way that, to handle the exception and could not get it from cache then must hit to database and get the values.

Comment: What happens then until connection is restored?
One server would read data from the cache and the other server from the DB. What is the conflict resolution strategy?